# CSVから読み込んだデータを元にfor文をつかってgooglecalnedarの情報を取得する

Tags: javascript, json

js初心者です。初歩的な質問かもしれませんがご容赦下さい。

CSVに格納しておいた複数のGoogleCalendarのID情報を読み込んできて、
そこからfor分を使ってループ処理をかけて、各カレンダーの情報を取り出す処理を考えました。

なぜかわからないのですが、カレンダー情報は取り出せるのですが、
CSVからID情報と付随して取得したランク情報がうまく反映されません。

コールバック関数やdefferを関数で使う形を調べましたが、
いまいちしっくりと来ませんでした。

お手数ですが、ご尽力お願い致します。

**問題点：**

実際に出力すると、irankの変数だけ挙動がおかしい。`data.items[0].summary`は特に問題なし。
→CSV最終行の文字列（`irank = csvListall[263][5] = b`）の値が全ての`irank`で代入されてしまう。

**今回求める結果：**

```
a +文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=0のとき
b +文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=1のとき
ss+文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=2のとき
c +文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=3のとき
b +文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=4のとき
ss+文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=5のとき
s +文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=6のとき
↓
続く...
```

**結果：**

```
b+文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=0のとき
b+文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=1のとき
b+文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=2のとき
b+文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=3のとき
b+文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=4のとき
b+文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=5のとき
b+文字列（data.items[0].summaryの結果← i=6のとき
↓
続く...
```

```js
function Kansu(){

//GOOGL CALEMDAR APIを使う時に必要なトークン
    var apikey = '個人のAPIキー';

//GOOGL CALEMDARで日付関係の処理
    var now = new Date();
    var y = now.getFullYear();
    var m = now.getMonth() + 1;
    var d = now.getDate();
    var w = now.getDay();
    var wd = ["日", "月", "火", "水", "木", "金", "土"];
    var h = now.getHours();
    var mi = now.getMinutes();
    var s = now.getSeconds();
    var mm = ("0" + m).slice(-2);
    var dd = ("0" + d).slice(-2);
    var hh = ("0" + h).slice(-2);
    var mmi = ("0" + mi).slice(-2);
    var ss = ("0" + s).slice(-2);

//GOOGL CALEMDAR明日の日付
    var dmax = now.getDate() + 1;
    var ddmax = ("0" + dmax).slice(-2);

//GOOGL CALEMDAR今日～明日の日付
    var timeMin = y + "-" + mm + "-" + dd + "T" + hh + ":" + mmi + ":" + ss + "Z";
    var timeMax = y + "-" + mmmax + "-" + dd + "T" + hh + ":" + mmi + ":" + ss + "Z";



//まずサーバー上のCSVからGoogle Calendarのアドレスを取得
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Google Calendarのアドレスを一覧化した.csv',
        success: function(era) {
        csvListall = $.csv()(era);

//取得したGoogle Calendarのアドレスを１行ずつ総当りでチェック（
    for(var i=0;i<264;i++){
    var calendarId = '';
    var calendarId = csvListall[i][2];

//取得したGoogle Calendarの各アドレスごとにあるランク情報（sss,ss,s,a,b,c）を取得
    var irank = '';
    var irank = csvListall[i][5];



//$.getJSONにてグーグルカレンダーから情報を取得
        var uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + calendarId + "/events?key=" + apikey + "&timeMin=" + timeMin + "&timeMax=" + timeMax + "&maxResults=10&orderBy=startTime&singleEvents=true";
        var jsinfo = uri;
            $.getJSON(jsinfo,
            function(data){
                //取得したsummaryが空じゃない時に実行
                if (data.items[0].summary != ""){
                //#imagesに文字列を代入
                    $("#images").append(irank + data.items[0].summary);
                         }
                    });
                }
            }
    });
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON`のコールバック関数`function(data)`で参照している`irank`は別の関数`function(era)`で定義されています。このため、`irank`の状態は`function(era)`が一回実行されるごとに1個確保されます。
一方`$.getJSON`はコールバック呼び出しを非同期に呼び出します。ですので`function(era)`で`$.getJSON`が264回呼び出された後に`function(data)`が264回実行され、`irank`の値はすべて264番目の状態となります。

`function(data)`を例えば以下のように書き換えると各呼び出し時の`irank`が保存されるようになるかと思います。

```
(function(irank){
    return function(data) {
        // …
    };
})(irank)
```

Answer (score 0):

原因はpgrhoさんが書かれている通りです。

いつかあなたが絶対に引っかかる、ある一つのJavaScriptの罠
http://qiita.com/ukiuni@github/items/463493a690265cec8bb7

別解としてfor文を使用せずに、[`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)や[`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)で配列内(csvListall)の値を1つずつ処理する方法もあります。

`Array.prototype.slice(0, 264)`で最初の要素から264個だけ処理するようにしていますが、csvListallの要素すべてに対して処理を行うのであれば、このメソッドは不要なので削除してください。

**jQuery.each():**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Google Calendarのアドレスを一覧化した.csv',
    success: function (era) {
        csvListall = $.csv()(era);

        //取得したGoogle Calendarのアドレスを１行ずつ総当りでチェック
        $.each(csvListall.slice(0, 264), function(index, value){
            var calendarId = value[2];

            //取得したGoogle Calendarの各アドレスごとにあるランク情報（sss,ss,s,a,b,c）を取得
            var irank = value[5];

            //...

        });
    }
});
```

**Array.prototype.forEach():**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Google Calendarのアドレスを一覧化した.csv',
    success: function (era) {
        csvListall = $.csv()(era);

        //取得したGoogle Calendarのアドレスを１行ずつ総当りでチェック
        csvListall
            .slice(0, 264)
            .forEach(function(value, index){
                var calendarId = value[2];

                //取得したGoogle Calendarの各アドレスごとにあるランク情報（sss,ss,s,a,b,c）を取得
                var irank = value[5];

                //...

            });
    }
});
```